How to reset local branch to remote without checking local branch
Similar to this other question
Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD
git reset --hard origin/master

But I want to do it without checking out master. I tried git reset master --hard origin/master but it complains fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.

If you want to change the head of a branch other than the one that's checked out, use git branch and --force it.

This may sound like a joke, but I'm fairly certain it will work in your case- just delete it! E.g: git branch -D master. (This should work because... what do you use master for? Either you don't need it at all because you can use origin/master instead, or you need to check it out at some point, and the next time you do it will be the latest version of origin/master anyway.)

@TTT Deleting a branch has some side effects, including that the reflog entries of the branch are also removed.

@ElpieKay Agreed. But I highly doubt OP is checking out a local master in order to use the reflog. (In fact, the idea of needing to know what local master was on prior to the reset, is the exact thing I had in mind when saying "fairly certain" instead of "certain".  I just can't think of a realistic use case for this.)

You may try:
# from some local branch other than master
git branch -f master origin/master

The -f switch will instruct Git to categorically replace the local master branch with the origin/master tracking branch.  If you also needed to first update the tracking branch, you could use:
git fetch origin
git branch -f master origin/master


A plain and safe solution is git update-ref.
git update-ref refs/heads/master origin/master

Note that here the full ref name refs/heads/master should be used instead of master. The latter creates .git/master and causes warning: refname 'master' is ambiguous. If it happens, you can just remove .git/master to solve the problem.
It works no matter if master is checked out or not.
